# How to Get the Second Checkbox Value in a Table Row Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to console.log the first value of a checkbox using

console.log(row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').value) as shown below.

How do I console.log the second value of a checkbox in a table row?   I still want to also be able to use the .theTable tr for the row.  The value is an attribute which makes this more challenging to me.  I will use this value as part of the conditional with the three checkmarks selected.

```js
/*function run() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable tr').forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked==false) {
      console.log(`the first checkbox of row ${i} is checked`);
    }
  })
}
*/

function run() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable tr').forEach((row, i) => {
    let allChecked = row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').length === row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length

    if (allChecked && row.querySelectorAll('select option:checked').length > 0 && row.querySelector('select option:checked').value !== '' ) {
      console.log('run conditional on row index ', i)
    }
    if (row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked) {
      console.log(`the first checkbox of row ${i} is checked`);
      console.log(row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').value)
    }
    if (row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').checked==false) {
      console.log(`the first checkbox of row ${i} is unchecked`);
     console.log(row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').value)
    }

    
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<table class='theTable'>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Apple" checked>Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue" checked>Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot" checked>Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple">apple</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option selected value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="AppleSecond">Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue">Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot">Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple2">apple2</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </form>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: `row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')[1]` will give you 2nd checkbox element, If you want all checkbox value you can use map and get the value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `row.querySelector` try using `row.querySelectorAll`. This will return all the checkboxes that are present in the specific row.

If you want exactly the second node of each row, you can use

`row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')[1]`

```js
function run() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.theTable tr').forEach((row, index) => {
    const secondNode = row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')[1];
    console.log(`
      second node of row ${index +1},
      checked status => ${secondNode.checked},
      node value => ${secondNode.value}`);
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<table class='theTable'>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Apple" checked>Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue" checked>Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot" checked>Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple">apple</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option selected value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="AppleSecond">Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue">Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot">Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple2">apple2</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am specifically looking for the second value of the checkbox on each row, specifically where the BananaValues are.

Comment: Thank you Nitheesh.  I just had to add the dot value to the end. 
 console.log(row.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')[1].value) is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function run() {
for(i=0; i < 1; i++){
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
var checkboxs= x.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]
console.log(checkboxs.value)
}
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="run()" />

<table class='theTable'>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Apple" checked>Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue" checked>Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot" checked>Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple">apple</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option selected value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="AppleSecond">Apple </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="BananaValue">Banana </label>
        <label> <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="Carrot">Carrot </label>
      </td>
      <td>

        Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="apple2">apple2</option>
          <option value="orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
          <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        </select>
      </td>

    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is not exact what you what but you can use this logic